# What role is とも playing in "それとも自殺？"

Tags: translation

The sentence pair

> それは殺人だったの？それとも自殺？

translates to

> Was it a murder or a suicide?

Can somebody help explain what role とも is playing in the second sentence?

Comment: それとも is a single word: https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments: それとも is a single word (https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%B6%E3%82%8C%E5%85%B1).

Comment: Given that それとも can be written as 其れ共, I'm assuming that the とも is not the particles と and も being added to 其? That is, there is no understanding this word (etymological or structural) in terms of its parts?